# Using Variable as Substring Parameter in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to extract the string before the last slash that I retrieve from my function; `:FIND_SLASH`. But when I echoed the result, it is displaying the variable name `ndxOfSlash`, instead of the extracted string.
The list.txt contains the sample input below.

**Sample Input:**

`AAA/BBBB/CCC/test.txt`

**Expected output:**

`AAA/BBBB/CCC/`

**Actual output:**

`ndxOfSlash`

**Code Snippet**

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in (list.txt) DO (

    set tempname=%%x
    call :FIND_SLASH indexSlash
    set ndxOfSlash=!indexSlash!
    call set fileDir=!!tempname:~0,!ndxOfSlash!!!
    echo !fileDir!

)
```

I also tried replacing the variable parameter; `ndxOfSlash`, with an actual number, and it was able to display the expected output.

I referred to this [site](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) when doing the substring.

Comment: Have you tried using ```@For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("list.txt") Do @Echo %%~pG``` or similarly, ```@For /F "UseBackQ EOL=? Delims=” %%G In ("list.txt") Do @Echo %%~dpG```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
call set fileDir=%%tempname:~0,!ndxOfSlash!%%
```

should fix the problem.